# set unique value for size of mp4

Tags: mp4

What I want to do is to have my mp4 always display the same size as if the user double-clicked on the mp4 while it was playing (i.e., with the black bars top and bottom), rather than opening up full screen.

How can I display the mp4 as described to begin with and not allow the user to change it?

My best guess is to change the frame size, but I am not certain this is the optimum approach.

Comment: Because I ended up answering my own question, I was tempted to just delete it.  However, in case the answer may be useful to others, I kept the question.  The answer is to set the scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone.  This does not prevent the user from changing it; however, at least it initially shows with the black bars.

Comment: your question and your comment do not help in any way. What is the platform? Mac/Win/Linux? What player are you using? Programming language?